# Can I use Tk in C++?

Tags: c++, tk-toolkit

I know that probably the most popular GUI framework for C++ is Qt. But was wondering if I can use something simpler, like Tk? Cant find any references, tutorials or info about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use.

See http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/

Read its documentation. See example at http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/examples/ex1.html.

Comment: Cool. How could I missed that when searching? Oh well. Thx.